# 2 Database Queries returned in 1 array

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 queries that get elements from 2 different databases

I want to return the query results in an array at the moment I have one array return but I want to merge the 2 queries into the one array.

```
//DB QUERY
$query1 = $this->A_db->get();

//DB QUERY
$query2 = $this->B_db->get();

if($query1->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, then array_merge() should work to extend one array with the other directly.

```
return array_merge($query1->result_array(), $query2->result_array());
```

Comment: can I add a fake column to the database query, so I want to add Application_ID as a value of 1. Thanks for your help

Comment: That would need to happen as part of the initial query, and has nothing to do with extending/merging arrays. You didn't mention what database, framework, etc. you're using, but to add a column in an SQL query, for example, at the time the query is run on a table named "baz" with columns "foo", "bar", you would do `select 1 as application_id, foo, bar from baz;` instead of just `select * from baz;`

Comment: created the fake column to the value of zero by adding "0 as appID" to the sql query